# Multiple elements using appendChild for table

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following `input` and `button`

```
const inputNotice = document.createElement("input");
inputNotice.type = "text";
r.insertCell(26).appendChild(inputNotice.cloneNode(true));

//new button

const Noticebutton = document.createElement("button");
Noticebutton.type = "button";
Noticebutton.textContent = "Send Notice";
r.insertCell(26).appendChild(Noticebutton);
```

Im trying to get the `input field` and `button` to sit in 1 `cell` in the table, it creates these in 2 separate cells.

Comment: 3 answers, 5 hours have passed, so far no response from your side. Please comment on the responses you received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a div having input and button as children and then append this as the child of the cell like this:

`const div= document.createElement('div');`

`const inputNotice = document.createElement('input');`

`const Noticebutton = document.createElement("button");`

`div.appendChild(inputNotice);`

`div.appendChild(NoticeButton);`

Comment: No need for a wrapper element. If you want to approach it this way, use a `DocumentFragment` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no `html` template provided, I have had one of my own to do the illustration.

***The idea is to add both of the elements inside a container and then append that container to the cell as a child***.

In the following illustration I have used a `div` as a container. Feel free to choose one of which that suits the needs.

---

### ***Illustration***

```js
const nonWorkingRow = document.querySelector('#cell-host-non-working');

const inputNotice = document.createElement("input");
inputNotice.type = "text";
// inputNotice.style.display = 'inline block';
nonWorkingRow.insertCell(0).appendChild(inputNotice.cloneNode(true));

//new button

const Noticebutton = document.createElement("button");
Noticebutton.type = "button";
Noticebutton.textContent = "Send Notice";
// Noticebutton.style.display = 'inline block';
nonWorkingRow.insertCell(0).appendChild(Noticebutton.cloneNode(true));

const workingRow = document.querySelector('#cell-host');

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.appendChild(inputNotice);
container.appendChild(Noticebutton);
workingRow.insertCell(0).appendChild(container);
```

```css
.column-bordered-table thead td {
  border-left: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  border-right: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}

.column-bordered-table td {
  border-left: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  border-right: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}

.column-bordered-table tfoot tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}
```

```html
<h1>Non Working</h1>
<table id="row-host-non-working" class="column-bordered-table">
  <tr id="cell-host-non-working" style="outline: thin solid">
    <td>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h1>Working</h1>
<table id="row-host-working" class="column-bordered-table">
  <tr id="cell-host" style="outline: thin solid">
    <td>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Comment: No need for a wrapper element. If you want to approach it this way, use a `DocumentFragment` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting a new cell twice (which is the cause of your problem), do that only once and work with the reference `insertCell` provides:

```js
const cell = r.insertCell(26);

const inputNotice = document.createElement("input");
inputNotice.type = "text";
const Noticebutton = document.createElement("button");
Noticebutton.type = "button";
Noticebutton.textContent = "Send Notice";

cell.append(inputNotice, Noticebutton);
```

Notice I'm using `append` here, not `appendChild`, because it allows to pass a number of elements to it rather than just one.